# Devexpress DXCharts (refresh, update, clear) new instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, devexpress, dependency-properties

I'm using wpf and c# with the Third party DevExpress Libraries. I'm having a problem with DXCharts. I've tried a few different things to clear or update the chart to no avail. I'm Data-binding to a Data-table(built on the fly) with a dependency property for the Data-source.

The dependency properties for the chart do not seem to be overridden when new data is set to the backing property. This gives me overlaying points on the chart. As you can see in the examples below.

**1st Set of Data**
[image: 1st set of Data Points]

**2nd Set of Data**
[image: 2nd set of Data Points]

I also tried creating new instances of the Chart control and its still showing the old binded dependency properties. The DXchart usercontrol is embedded into a Content Control. I bind the Chart via a content property. All of this is nested under a DevExpress tab control.

Here is some of the code below:

**Dependency Properties**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTableChartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        ("DataTableChart", typeof(DataTable), typeof(MainWindowViewModel));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentElementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        ("ContentElement", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(MainWindowViewModel));
```

**Backing Properties**

```
public DataTable DataTableChart
    {
        get { return (DataTable)this.GetValue(DataTableChartProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DataTableChartProperty, value); }

public FrameworkElement ContentElement
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)this.GetValue(ContentElementProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ContentElementProperty, value); }
    }
```

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Reporting_DIMS.UI.ChartControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
         xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
         xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/charts"
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
         xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="1100">
<Grid>
    <Border Padding="3">
        <dxc:ChartControl Margin="0" Name="chartControl" DataSource="{Binding DataTableChart}">
            <dxc:ChartControl.Diagram>
                <dxc:XYDiagram2D SeriesDataMember="DIMS User">
                    <dxc:XYDiagram2D.SeriesTemplate>
                        <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D ValueDataMember="Count" ArgumentDataMember="Entry DateTime" />
                    </dxc:XYDiagram2D.SeriesTemplate>
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D>
            </dxc:ChartControl.Diagram>
            <dxc:ChartControl.Legend>
                <dxc:Legend x:Name="legend"/>
            </dxc:ChartControl.Legend>
        </dxc:ChartControl>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**Small MainWindow Portion**

```
<dx:DXTabItem Header="Log Charts" Name="dXTabItem2">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Content="{Binding     ContentElement}"/>
                </dx:DXTabItem>
```

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I figured out the problem it was totally unrelated to the dependency properties. I had stale data sticking in a dataset that was being migrated to the new datatable. I just created a new instance and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the old charting object and creating a new one. This is the intended behavior of the Charts per DevExpress.

Answer (score 2):

rreeves is correct.  A simple workaround for me was to wrap my DXChartControl in a 2nd ContentControl.  Instead of binding directly to the ChartControl, let an inner ContentControl hand the binding to the ChartControl, that way,when the content is changed, the ContentControl generates a new instance via the ContentTemplate.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="chartTemplate">
        <dex:ChartControl DataSource="{Binding}" DataContextChanged="chartControl_DataContextChanged_1"/>
    </DataTemplate>     
    <ContentControl  Grid.Row="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=chartTemplate}" Content="{Binding 'YOUR ITEMSSOURCE'}"/>
```

Then you can rebuil the Chart in the DataContextChanged.

Hope this helps!